# Scapy not working with Python 3.6. Import problems with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I am trying to test a simple code that will inspect a .pcap file using scapy. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and my Python version is 3.6.

However when I do: `from scapy.all import *` I get the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy.all'`.

When I change this to be `from scapy import *`, I get an error later in my code when I try and use the scapy sendrecv sniff function. I get the error `NameError: name 'sniff' is not defined`. Note if I switch from sniff() to rdpcap() I get the same error but its now "rdpcap is not defined".

I've read through a bunch of previous stack overflow answers and nothing is helping. My python script name is "pcap_grapher.py", so the issue is **not** the script name being scapy.py.

When I run `pip3 install scapy` in the terminal I get the message `Requirement already satisfied: scapy in /home/vic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.4.4)`

I've also tried running `pip3 install --pre scapy[basic]` as the docs recommend here: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html but it didn't help.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am super stuck.

Comment: Can you try this: `import scapy ; scapy.__file__` in the python interpreter? (just for checking it points to the appropriate scapy version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you will never be able to import `sniff()` from `scapy`, since it is within the submodule `scapy.all`. There are two ways I can think of to fix this:

1. Since you're on Ubuntu, try running `sudo apt-get install python3-scapy` and see if it lets you run `from scapy.all import sniff` now.
2. Check the path that python is currently pulling from by typing the following in terminal:

```
$ which scapy
  /location-of-scapy-on-your-system
```

Then run

```
$ python
  >>> import os
  >>> scapy_path = "/location-of-scapy-on-your-system"
  >>> if not scapy_path in os.sys.path: os.sys.path.append(scapy_path)
```

That should hopefully fix things. If not, it's possible you installed the wrong version of scapy: you can check this by running

```
$ python
  >>> import scapy
  >>> print(scapy.__version__)
```

Comment: Okay so if I do the last command with "python3" in the command terminal, it works and gives me scapy version 2.4.4. However, when I then go to launch my python script with the command "python3 pcap_grapher.py" I get that there is no module named "scapy.all"

Comment: No worries! I saw your edit. It still seems like an issue with python3 using the wrong path for your modules - let me think about it for a sec. In any case, version 2.4.4 *is* the latest version for python3.

Comment: So I just edited the first comment, because I removed and re-installed scapy and it fixed the first error I was having. Sorry for the confusion, I didn't expect a response that fast!

Comment: Can you post what ```print(os.sys.path)``` returns, and also what ```which scapy``` returns? Also, I just realized - did you use *sudo*` when you ran ```pip3 install scapy```? Sometimes if you haven't configured it, the ```sudo``` path can differ from the normal install location.

Comment: My scapy path is "/home/vic/.local/bin/scapy" when I type "which scapy" into the command line. 

print(os.sys.path) returns: ['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/vic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Comment: I retried the install with 'sudo pip3 install scapy' and got the response: Requirement already satisfied: scapy in /home/vic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.4.4)

Comment: Actually, try ```$ mv /home/vic/.local/bin/scapy /home/vic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages```. That should move scapy from ```.local/bin``` (which is not in os.sys.path) to ```.local/lib``` (which is in os.sys.path). I think that should fix it.

Comment: I got error: "cannot overwrite directory '/home/vic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy' with non-directory". Even weirder, when I navigate to that directory, the scapy files are already there like scapy is installed. The command "which scapy" points to /home/vic/.local/bin/scapy still...

Comment: Try ```cd``` to get to your home directory, then ```vim ~/.bashrc```, then edit your PYTHONPATH variable (it should be blank) by doing ```export PYTHONPATH=/home/vic/.local/bin```, then exit the file and run ```source ~/.bashrc```. After that, close your terminal window and open a new one, and check that it's been updated by running ```echo $PYTHONPATH``` and it should print out the right dir. Then try running ```pcap_grapher.py``` again.

Comment: Another uninstall and reinstall seemed to fix it? I'm not sure why. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Probably because you edited the path, and reinstalling it now reinstalled it in the right location, finally. No worries! If you think my replies helped, please hit the green checkmark up at the top left of my original post. Good luck!